# Copy/paste dialog in android showing only english for both english and spanish layout language change

Tags: android

I am using English,Arabic,Farsi and spanish language layouts.

If I'm in English layout the dialog shows in English like copy/paste thats good.

When I change it to Spanish then also the dialog showing copy/paste.

Same for Arabic and Farsi both showing copy/paste dialog in Arabic.

How to change copy/paste dialog with multiple languages?

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to have a lot of layouts to have different languages, just edit your `Strings` values into `res - Strings` , you can create more than one String for different texts, and then programatically with your layout you can change the language depending on the phone and people location

See this : https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

ps: with the same string id, you can have more than one language, the phone will choose in which language it pulls the text from Strings.xml